# Dockerfile weird behaviour when copying

Tags: javascript, docker, dockerfile

I am building a dockerfile from a SPA using very basic js and html

I want to copy only some files to the docker image, but I am really struggling to do so as following: [docker file commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqgJH.png)

I have also tried several variations, i.e removing ./ from the index html, also doing it on one line using "array" style...
But all these tries end up in writing the index.html content to all files, for example I will see the index html content inside the style.css,seeing it from the dev Tools on chrome. Therefore the page won't work as expected

The only workaround I have managed to get working is making a script using copy and placing everything on a "dist" folder, then copying everything on the folder to the docker image.
That way it would work, but I'd prefer not to use a script and instead copy everything needed from the dockerfile straight away.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should try an include as much information as possible.  An example of the DOCKERFILE would be good as we can see what you have attempted.

Comment: Hello, the dockerfile content is on the attached image link, as I cannot post images directly because being a newbie. Anyways just after posting the question I found out what I was missing, it's on the below answer... Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `docker build` takes a text-format Dockerfile, not an image, and you should include that text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after more than 5h trying workarounds, I found out the question myself. Problem was not understanding COPY command, I was copying files to the root, instead of placing them on the correct folder:
[Correct Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMN2p.png)

Notice the folder where every file is copied to